# How can I add customized selection value into DropDownListFor with ViewBag for options?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a DropDownListFor with ViewBag as SelectList and looking to add one more option into dropdown with text as "Not Applicable" and value null.

Code on the ViewData:

```
ViewData["RegionID"] = new SelectList(_context.Region, nameof(LocationMaster.Region.RegionId), nameof(LocationMaster.Region.Name));
```

Current code on DropDownListFor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RegionID, (SelectList) ViewBag.RegionID, "Select Region", new {@class = "form-control", @data_val = "true", @data_val_required= "Region is required"})
```

Can I like append or insert one more item into the ViewData?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a variable (`regionOptions`) to hold the list of regions.
2. With `Insert(int index, T value)` to add a default option as the first element of the `regionOptions` array.

```cs
var regionOptions = _context.Region.Select(x => new
{
    RegionId = (int?)x.RegionId,
    Name = x.Name
}).ToList();

regionOptions.Insert(0, new { RegionId = (int?)null, Name = "Not Applicable" });
            
ViewData["RegionID"] = new SelectList(regionOptions, nameof(LocationMaster.Region.RegionId), nameof(LocationMaster.Region.Name));
```

3. Remove the placeholder: "Select Region"

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RegionID, (SelectList) ViewBag.RegionID, new {@class = "form-control", @data_val = "true", @data_val_required= "Region is required"})
```

[Demo (MVC) @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JQ6XkF)

*Note that you should remove the data validation `@data_val = "true", @data_val_required= "Region is required"` if you allow the `RegionID` drop-down list as not mandatory.*

---

Or as you add the placeholder: "Select Region", you don't have to manually add the default option into `ViewData["RegionID"]`. By default its value is blank.